# Cannot set volumeMounts to a specific container using Kubernetes Java client

Tags: java, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes Java client (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) to deploy a Job on the cluster.
It seems setting volumeMounts does not work properly while setting image is OK.

Here is an outline of my current code:

```
//Create Job as it has one initContainer and one container.
V1Job job = new V1Job();
V1Container containerA = new V1Container();
V1Container containerB = new V1Container();
...(omitted)

//Create references to each container
containerA = job.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().getInitContainers().get(0);
containerB = job.getSpec().getTemplate().getSpec().getContainers().get(0);

//These work well, each image is set to corresponding container.
containerA.setImage("imageA");
containerB.setImage("imageB");

//I think this method should set volume "dirAAA" to only containerA,
//but both containerA and containerB will have the volume "dirAAA".
V1VolumeMount volumeMount = new V1VolumeMount().mountPath("/AAA").name("dirAAA");
containerA.addVolumeMountsItem(volumeMount);
```

I don't understand why `containerA.addVolumeMountsItem(volumeMount)` sets volumeMount to not only containerA but also containerB.
Actually I am new to Java development, now struggling to solve this problem.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 2 containers are on the same pod ?

Comment: Yes. First one is a initContainer and second is a normal container.